# Can't create file for production environment

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I use Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and Golang.

My local environment can run code, but Production Environment (GCP) can't.

I see log. =>

```
open stylesheet/qrcode.png: no such file or directory 
read-only file system
```

So I try chmod. ex) chmod 644 or 777 qrcode.png

I am trying to create the image: `qrcode.png` <= It's dummy file.
But the code does not run.

Is there any other way?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/png"
    "log" ............

    "github.com/boombuler/barcode"
    "github.com/boombuler/barcode/qr"
)


func createQr() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    result = ""
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        s := strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(10))
        result = result + s
    }
    qrCode, _ := qr.Encode(result, qr.M, qr.Auto) //info
    qrCode, _ = barcode.Scale(qrCode, 200, 200)   //size

    PIN, _ = strconv.Atoi(result)
    file, _ := os.Create("stylesheet/qrcode.png")
    defer file.Close()

    // encode the barcode as png
    png.Encode(file, qrCode)
    fmt.Println(file)

    starttime = time.Now()
}
```

```
file, _ := os.Create("stylesheet/qrcode.png")
```

This code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're deploying to App Engine Standard, you may only write to [`/tmp` folder in the filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-temp-files).

Be careful though with what you intend to do with the generated file. Having generated it in the filesystem of one instance does not make it available for serving like your app's CSS and JS files. Also instances are meant to be stateless, your next request may hit any other instance, and any instance is often shutdown by the autoscaler.

My advice would be:

- if you want to serve it only once right away, then have your handler do only this and stream the QR-code PNG bytes to the `ResponseWriter` (which implements `io.Writer`) and set the appropriate response header `content-type`. No need to use a file.
- if you need the generated image file to be persistent, then store it either in Cloud Storage or Firestore. Then you would need a strategy to properly serve it over https (object access rights in Cloud Storage, App Engine handler for Firestore).

Also, always check and handle the errors, never swallow them with `_`!

Answer (score 0):

Does your production environment have a network path to github to import.  Look at your log files and you may find that it can't find github.  Most production environments don't have a network path to the internet.

You'll have to download and ship these external packages as part of your code base.